# Jetpack Compose ViewModel not updating on load

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my Android app, using Jetpack compose I have a Model object that I am writing to disk to persist the application state. This is working fine, but the problem I have is as follows.
When the app starts up, the UI is drawn & the viewModel instance is created. The init function is called which loads the data from a file into the viewModel. However, the data loaded from the file is not reflected in the UI, until there is an interaction that modifies the state of the viewModel. I believe this is because the ui is drawn before the data is loaded from the file into the viewModel.
My question is, how can I have this data reflected in the UI on app load?
Here is my viewModel

```
class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(GameState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<GameState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    private val fileName = "game_state.json"

    private lateinit var context: Context

    private lateinit var gson: Gson
    fun init(context: Context, gson: Gson) {
        this.context = context
        this.gson = gson

        _uiState.value = loadGameStateFromFile()
    }


     private fun addPoint(team: Team) {
            if (team == Team.HOME) {
                _uiState.update { currentState ->
                    currentState.copy(
                        hPoints = _uiState.value.hPoints.plus(1)
                    )
                }
                saveGameStateToFile(_uiState.value)
            } else {
                _uiState.update { currentState ->
                    currentState.copy(
                        aPoints = _uiState.value.aPoints.plus(1)
                    )
                }
                saveGameStateToFile(_uiState.value)
            }
        }
//other functions that modify the state here

    private fun reset(): GameState {
        val gameState = GameState()
        _uiState.value = gameState
        return gameState

    }

    private fun loadGameStateFromFile(): GameState {
        val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName)
        val gameState: GameState
        return if (file.exists()) {
            val jsonString = file.readText()
            gameState = gson.fromJson(jsonString, GameState::class.java)
            gameState
        } else {
            GameState()
        }
    }

    private fun saveGameStateToFile(gameState: GameState) {
        val jsonString = gson.toJson(gameState)
        val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName)
        file.writeText(jsonString)
    }
}
```

This is where it is initialized in MainActivity and passed to the UI objects

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create()

        val gameViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GameViewModel::class.java)
        gameViewModel.init(this.application, gson)

        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault)
        setContent {
//            KeepScreenOn()
            Scaffold(
                timeText = {
                    TimeText(
                        timeTextStyle = TimeTextDefaults
                            .timeTextStyle(fontSize = 8.sp)
                    )
                },
            ) {
                RefereeScoreKeeperTheme {
                    Watchface(gameViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my WatchFace implementation

```
@Composable
fun Watchface(gameViewModel: GameViewModel) {
    val gameUiState by gameViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    Stopwatch()
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(.5f)
                .padding(bottom = 5.dp)
                .background(gameUiState.homeColor.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
        ) {
            TotalPointsBox(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 24.dp),
                totalPoints = gameUiState.totalHomeScore,
                diff = gameUiState.homeDiff
            )
            ScoreDisplayBox(
                text = gameUiState.homeScore,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
            )
            Row {
                ScoreActionBox(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(.5f)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    subtractScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.SubtractHomeGoal) },
                    addScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.AddHomeGoal) },
                    shouldVibrate = gameUiState.hGoals != 0
                )
                ScoreActionBox(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(.5f)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    subtractScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.SubtractHomePoint) },
                    addScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.AddHomePoint) },
                    shouldVibrate = gameUiState.hPoints != 0
                )
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(.5f)
                .padding(top = 5.dp)
                .background(gameUiState.awayColor.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
        ) {
            TotalPointsBox(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .padding(vertical = 20.dp),
                totalPoints = gameUiState.totalAwayScore,
                diff = gameUiState.awayDiff
            )
            ScoreDisplayBox(
                text = gameUiState.awayScore,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
            )
            Row {
                ScoreActionBox(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(.5f)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    subtractScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.SubtractAwayGoal) },
                    addScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.AddAwayGoal) },
                    shouldVibrate = gameUiState.aGoals != 0

                )
                ScoreActionBox(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(.5f)
                        .fillMaxHeight(),
                    subtractScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.SubtractAwayPoint) },
                    addScore = { gameViewModel.onAction(ScoreAction.AddAwayPoint) },
                    shouldVibrate = gameUiState.aPoints != 0

                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you loading data from main thread?

Comment: I believe so. This is a very simple app with a single UI screen. I've not explicitly delegated it to another thread.